# Codeigniter multilanguage and adding the language to the url for seo

Tags: codeigniter, multilingual

I read this
[the best way to make codeigniter website multi-language. calling from lang arrays depends on lang session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328420/the-best-way-to-make-codeigniter-website-multi-language-calling-from-lang-arrays)

for language inclusion...
i wonder how the url will appear for multi languages...

How to show the language in url so that it will also be indexed in search engines...

for example sitenameDOTcom/es or sitenameDOTcom/whoweare/es or something like this and how to sync with the controllers and the urls...

Comment: try this repo https://github.com/waqleh/codeigniter-language-in-url-internationalization

Answer (score 22, accepted):

ah, i found an article in the codeigniter forums.
here it is ...

https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/URI-Language-Identifier

previously the url was like the following and now it doesn't work.
*http://codeigniter.com/wiki/URI_Language_Identifier/*

and here is a live example i am using

http://vikku.info/wordreminder/en

Comment: and yet there is another huge one. just look at it.
http://codeigniter.com/wiki/i18n_Multi-language_Library_Helper/

Comment: Thanks for posting that link.  The URI_Language_Identifier was just what I wanted.  Simple URL language specification and nothing else.

Comment: url changed to: https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/URI-Language-Identifier