# Redirect URL multilanguage Codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, redirect

I'm adding multilanguage options for a website in CodeIgniter.

I'm using this library

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/CodeIgniter-2.1-internationalization-i18n

The only problem i'm having is if y access www.domain.com 
The redirect goes to www.domain.com/es/welcome/index

```
$route['default_controller'] = "welcome/index";
$route['^(es|en)'] = "welcome/index";
$route['^(es|en)/(.+)$'] = "welcome/$2";
```

I don't know how to only redirect to www.domain.com/es or www.domain.com/en
when entering www.domain.com

Is that possible with this library?

Comment: see this url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2823831/codeigniter-multilanguage-and-adding-the-language-to-the-url-for-seo

Answer (score 0):

```
//$this->default_uri = $RTR->default_controller;
$this->default_uri = '';
```

change line in MY_Lang.php