# Codeigniter: multi language using language helper and database

Tags: database, codeigniter, multilingual

My language file `(application/language/english/english_lang.php);`

```
$CI =& get_instance(); 

foreach($CI->db->get('language')->result() as $language):

    $lang[''.$language->name.''] = "".$language->turkish.".";

endforeach;
```

My database;

> > SELECT `id`, `name`, `english`, `turkish`, `create_date` FROM `language` WHERE 1

My view file;

> > echo lang('title','title');

But it is not working...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328420/the-best-way-to-make-codeigniter-website-multi-language-calling-from-lang-array

Comment: Did you actually read the codeigniter documentation? Here: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html. And are you sure you want to hit the database on every page load just to retrieve the text lines. What happends when you have a million lines in the database?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like the solution:

[Language Class Extended DB](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/Language-Class-Extended-DB)