# multilanguage codeigniter php, mysql best approach

Tags: codeigniter, multilingual

Hi can anyone show me an approach of how to code a multilanguage website that not only change the menu and also the title and content of an article.

Basically, i think each time i write an article, i will write it into 2 language seperately, and then insert it into mysql. and when i change the language at the front-end everything will change to another language and remain at that language until i change it back

So, anyone show me a best approach for this. Please i need it urgently

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think your approach is correct. I have some sites with a similar approach.

Comment: I usually have separate views for each language, and determine which view to load, and which data to pull from the database depending on the URL string.

Answer (score 0):

H,

Use codeigniter language class http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user_guide/libraries/language.html

There some older posts here. Have a look   [the best way to make codeigniter website multi-language. calling from lang arrays depends on lang session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328420/the-best-way-to-make-codeigniter-website-multi-language-calling-from-lang-array)

Regards

iijb

Answer (score 0):

Content like: Menu, Buttons, Messages don t have to go to database. 
Use CI and language class to handle those.

Use database for different languages if you have dynamic content, like a blog posts or news and articles.

A controller would be something like this:

```
    class Language extends CI_Controller{

    function Language(){
        parent::__construct();
    }

    function change($language = null){  
        $language = urldecode($language);

        switch($language){

            case "English":
                $this->session->set_userdata('lang_id', 2);
                $this->session->set_userdata('lang_name', 'english');
                redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'refresh');

            break;

            case "Deutsch":
                $this->session->set_userdata('lang_id', 3);
                $this->session->set_userdata('lang_name', 'deutsch');
                redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'refresh');

            break;

            default:
                $this->session->set_userdata('lang_id', 3);
                $this->session->set_userdata('lang_name', 'deutsch');
                redirect($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'refresh');

            break;

        }

    }
}
```

And going to the index of a page/class:

```
//LOAD LANGUAGE SETTINGS
        $lang = $this->session->userdata('lang_name');

        if($lang != ''){
            //load default language folder
            $this->lang->load('home');
            $this->lang->load('extra_menu');
            $this->lang->load('base_menu');
            $this->lang->load('breadcrumbs');

        }else{
            //load language file and folder
            $this->lang->load('home', $this->session->userdata('lang_name'));
            $this->lang->load('extra_menu', $this->session->userdata('lang_name'));
            $this->lang->load('base_menu', $this->session->userdata('lang_name'));
            $this->lang->load('breadcrumbs', $this->session->userdata('lang_name'));                
        }
```