# How to make Multilingual website using library in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, multilingual

How can i add multi language in codeigniter?
I need my website in different languages.
Languages can select from a dropdown in the header.
According to the selected language, 
the complete website would be in selected language.
Am using latest version of codeigniter.

Comment: You can create using codeigniter user guide. refer : http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html

Comment: Then try this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328420/the-best-way-to-make-codeigniter-website-multi-language-calling-from-lang-array]

Comment: You mean are you storing different record for different language?

Comment: I referred this doc
http://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/language.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use codeigniter language class even if you are taking data from db. Store language array key in db.

For eg,

in language file there is one entry

```
$lang['hello'] = "hello in english";
```

You can store hello in db and and get it as

```
$dbdata = 'hello';//taken from db
```

And use that in your controller/view as

```
echo $this->lang->line($dbdata);
```

If you have any doubt about codeigniter language class, have a look at some older posts here.

[the best way to make codeigniter website multi-language. calling from lang arrays depends on lang session?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328420/the-best-way-to-make-codeigniter-website-multi-language-calling-from-lang-array)

Regards

iijb

Comment: i have to add so many languages. and messages from users have to change into different languages. so i cant predetermine all words. So how can i do it