# How to deal with navigation menu in a template for a multilingual site codeiginiter

Tags: codeigniter, templates, multilingual

i'm developping a website with 4 Languages(arabic , fransh,english,espagnol),using CodeIgniter ,  i'm begging with, by creating the template , but i dont know how to handle the template with the navigation list & the language , to detect the right language,all the examples of multilangue are basics.;any help will be appreciated , tutos , steps ,ideas ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with [CodeIgniter's Language Library](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/language.html).

For more read the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328420/the-best-way-to-make-codeigniter-website-multi-language-calling-from-lang-array). This can help you!

**UPDATE:** Also Check this [library](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/i18n-Multi-language-Library-Helper)

If you want to use template, when you can do it [CodeIgniter Template](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html)

Comment: I checked these libraries , i want to know if i have to create for each language a template ?

Comment: How to call the naviagtion menu for each language ?