# $this->lang->line reads only english language ( codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am developing multilanguage website with codeigniter. There are different language folders with _lang.php files in the application/language folder. However, it reads only in from english folder.

```
<?php echo $this->lang->line('share_face');?>
```

Could you tel me please what is the problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you do `$this->lang->load('filename', 'language');` to load your correct language?

Comment: I located that file in the controller in the constract function? Is that right?

Comment: If your language is loaded correctly, then I suggest you to use the `lang('share_face');` function. It is better to use, and fortunately it is shorter too. :)

Comment: @Nan check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328420/the-best-way-to-make-codeigniter-website-multi-language-calling-from-lang-array?rq=1 . It has all the information you need to successfully enable multilingualism on your site

Comment: @ sotoz , thanks a lot, looks informative i will read that