# How to create Hindi website in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, hindi

I need create a website which should available to the users in Hindi as well as in English.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

When I try to save `hindi_lang.php` it's not saving just giving unicode error..

Comment: [Have](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html) [you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6112132/how-to-setup-codeigniter-for-a-truly-multi-language-website) [read](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/wiki/CodeIgniter-2.1-internationalization-i18n) [these](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291318/internationalization-on-codeigniter-config-files)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, CodeIgniter has a nifty class called [`Language`](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/language.html). You can create language files for hindi and store it in a folder system/language/hindi

At the cost of repeating what the documentation says:

## Creating Language Files

Language files must be named with `_lang.php` as the file extension. For example, let's say you want to create a file containing error messages. You might name it: `error_lang.php`

Within the file you will assign each line of text to an array called `$lang` with this prototype:

```
$lang['language_key'] = "The actual message to be shown";
```

Note: It's a good practice to use a common prefix for all messages in a given file to avoid collisions with similarly named items in other files. For example, if you are creating error messages you might prefix them with error_

```
$lang['error_email_missing'] = "You must submit an email address";
$lang['error_url_missing'] = "You must submit a URL";
$lang['error_username_missing'] = "You must submit a username";
```

You then load the language file like you load anything else in CI, `$this->lang->load('filename', 'language');`

Answer (score 0):

Use the i18n library with hindi unicodes.